# jQuery not taking effect immediately

Tags: jquery, css, hover, effects, fade

Is there any reason for my jQuery effects not to be taking effect immediately? I have jQuery hover fade effects, but then I also have CSS rollovers as backups for anyone who has javascript disabled. What happens is when you load a page and roll over a link, you get the CSS effect, but any time after that, you get the nice, smooth jQuery effect. This must be repeated for every link. Is there a fix for this?

My jQuery code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".nav-link").hover(function() {
 $(this).animate({ color: "#669900" }, 250);
 return false;
}, 
function() {
 $(this).animate({ color: "#999999" }, 250);
});

$(".twit-link").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({ color: "#0099CC" }, 250);
  return false;
}, 
function() {
 $(this).animate({ color: "#999999" }, 250);
});

$(".rss-link").hover(function() {
 $(this).animate({ color: "#CC6600" }, 250);
  return false;
}, 
function() {
  $(this).animate({ color: "#999999" }, 250);
});

$(".sidebar-item").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({ color: "#669900"}, 250);
  return false;
}, 
function() {
  $(this).animate({ color: "#333333"}, 250);
});

$(".archive-link").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({ color: "#666666"}, 250);
  return false;
}, 
function() {
  $(this).animate({ color: "#999999"}, 250);
});

$(".sub").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({ 'background-color': '#336600'}, 250);
  return false;
}, 
function() {
  $(this).animate({ 'background-color': '#669900'}, 250);
});

$(".post-sb").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 1.0,
   'filter': 'alpha(opacity = 100)'}, 250);
  return false;
}, 
function() {
  $(this).animate({ 'opacity': .25,
   'filter': 'alpha(opacity = 25)'}, 250);
});

});
```

I'm getting my jQuery straight from Google (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js)

I'm using Safari.
Right now, I'm testing my site with MAMP, so its local on my computer, but eventually it will go to an external server.

Comment: Can you post your jQuery code?  This would help, a lot.

Comment: Can you say which browser you're using, and where you're serving the jQuery from? In some browsers you can see how long it takes for resources associated with the HTML file to download. (Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome.)

Comment: Is this live/on an exterior server or on your own computer?

Comment: please add 4 spaces before the odd lines to make the whole code readable better see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: The animations are provided in jQueryUI, not jQuery. Where are you serving the jQueryUI library from?

Comment: Do you have the same delay when viewing the preview here: http://jsbin.com/avabe/edit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your CSS has an immediate hover effect, it just precedes jQuery and changes the styles before your hover event has a chance to kick in.  I would disable these styles, or change the style on the elements when jQuery loads so the CSS `:hover` selectors are no longer in effect.

In your HTML you could have for example:

```
<a class="nav-link njs">My Link</a>
```

In your CSS:

```
.nav-link { color: #999999 }
.njs.nav-link:hover { color: #669900; }
```

In your jQuery:

```
$(".njs").removeClass("njs"); //Disable the hovers
```

Also, I'd suggest a function here to simplify looking at that code:

```
$(function() {
  $(".njs").removeClass("njs");
  setColors(".nav-link", "#669900", "#999999");
  setColors(".twit-link", "#0099CC", "#999999");
  setColors(".rss-link", "#CC6600", "#999999");
  setColors(".sidebar-item", "#669900", "#333333");
  setColors(".archive-link", "#666666", "#999999");
  setColors(".twit-link", "#0099CC", "#999999");

  $(".sub").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'background-color': '#336600'}, 250);
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'background-color': '#669900'}, 250);
  });

  $(".post-sb").hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(250);
  }, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(250, 0.25);
  });

});

function setColors(selector, hColor, nColor) {
 $(selector).hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ color: hColor}, 250);
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({ color: nColor}, 250);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but try negating the CSS with JavaScript right before you set the effect. You can add a class like `anotherClass:hover` with the CSS for the hover effect and then remove the class with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery file locally. Even Google can't compete with things being served from your own computer, and it's not impossible that the delay you see here won't be reflected once it's online.